# When does a Taylor expansion have only nonnegative coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Maybe the question is obvious, but I don't know the answer

Let $p(x_{1},...,x_{r})$ be a polynomial with nonnegative coefficients and consider
$$
F_{n}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}(p(x))^{k}
$$
where $x = (x_{1},...,x_{r}) \in \mathbb{R}^{r}$. Suppose $F_{n}$ converges uniformly to some function $f$. Now the coefficient of the taylor expansion of $F_{n}$ around **$0$** are nonnegative. Can I conclude that the coefficients of the taylor epansion of $f$ around 0  are also nonnegative?

Comment: What do you mean by "all coefficients of $f$ are nonnegative"?

Comment: I have edited my question. Sorry!

Comment: Well the exponential function is one example. So is fx = 1.

Comment: but is there a general result for rational functions?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** This was an answer to the question before it was edited.

No. Take for example $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}. $$
Then by the geometric series formula
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{1-(-x^2)} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^kx^{2k}, $$
whenever $|x| < 1$.
By the uniqueness of Taylor expansions, we know that this is the Taylor expansion of $f$ at $0$, but its coefficients are certainly not nonnegative.

Comment: The reason why I'm asking this question is that I read a paper and there is given a rational function $f : (-1,1)^{r} \xrightarrow{} \mathbb{R}$ which is the uniform limit of some functions $f_{n}$ on the same domain. Then it was stated that all the coefficients of the taylor expansion of $f$ around 0 are nonnegtive since the coefficients of $f$ are nonnegative

Comment: @love_math I would guess that some further restrictions are needed on $f$ to obtain such a result

Comment: can you mention some restrictions?

Comment: @love_math I cannot come up with anything out of the blue. However, you could of course just require all derivatives of $f$ at $0$ to be nonnegative.

Comment: Say we have a polynomial $f(x_{1},...,x_{r}) = \sum_{i_{1},...,i_{r}}a_{i_{1},...,i_{r}}x_{1}^{i_{1}}...x_{r}^{r}$. Suppose all coefficients are not zero. What can I say now about the coefficient of the  taylor expansion around $0$?

Comment: @love_math Well, a polynomial is already its own Taylor expansion, so then the result obviously holds. But I thought that we were discussing rational functions?

Comment: If I have a rational function $f(x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ such that deg$(p)$ = deg$(q)$ and all coefficient of $p$ and $q$ are nonnegative. What can I say now?

Comment: @love_math I understand what you want, but as I already said, I myself do not know of any results that could help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82963/discussion-between-love-math-and-sobi).

Comment: I have edited my question